# Android multiple button click

Tags: android, button

Android multiple button click

I have a button and I want on the button's first click i display a thing, and on it's second i display another etc ..

I have a button and want it to have 11 clicks .. on the first click `Num.settext("First");`
on second click `Num.settext("Second");`
etc .. until the tenth click .. then on the 11th click its's `Num.settext("0");` and it resets from the begning ..

like ..

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11(0) 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11(0)
```

Comment: nothing .. i didn't manage to find any tut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't be easier if you store the click number in a variable?

For instance:

```
    //...
    int clickNumber = 0;
    //...

    public void onClick() {

       if(clickNumber > 10) {//reset variable
         clickNumber = 0;
       }           

       if(clickNumber == 0) {
         Num.setText("First");
         clickNumber++;
       }
       else if(clickNumber == 1) {
         Num.setText("Second");
         clickNumber++;
       }
       //...

    }
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a field called cycle and an array of texts.

Then on click:

```
Num.setText(texts[cycle]);
cycle=(cycle + 1)%texts.length;
```